# How to restrict website access? for whole domain site?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, security, web

I have website django based, i need access control domain based like. I already established django own auth system and 2-auth system. I need for whole domain access control even for the static files.
If that possible only access code not username and password, and this need to be hard coded env or something like this.

Django version v4.0, Hosting Heroku

Comment: You need to serve static files manually with authentication check, but could you explain why do you want so? It means, for example, that login page will be rendered without css and js and it is hardly appropriate. Or configure nginx/apache/whatever you use to use simple auth (login+password) for static directory.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I developing in-house website not public, its stored a lot of sensitive document, already have user and password and momentary  access only by online  admin permit this is you need to able to access by call to admin. So i cover datebase check, i need exstra layer for static files.

Comment: @SUTerliakov as you said i can manually serve static files but this need to be served like future proof, for example 5 years later someone at team develop new app and not writing python like now so i need way for that

Answer (score 0):

For file protection you can create the fast tiny view, which send files back.
url for this view you can wrap with `permission_required`

```
urlpatterns += [
    path("media/", permission_required('users.can_download', login_url='/')(Download.as_view()), name="download"),
    ...
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator

Every moment you can revoke this permission from every user.

Comment: yes i have  this                                                                                                               '@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)


urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve,
                        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})]'

Comment: but again this not i thinking,this only redirect login page which as you know backend by database.

Comment: How you want to use it? Image goes through GET. You can add Secret Key in Image path or querystring. After that it IS Not Secret Key any more. You can send in Post Secret Key for every document and check it in View. Bit it Not works for simply static Files Like Image, css etc

Comment: i simple need a system don't depend on any programming language specific, like cloudflare IP Access rules but instead of IP need access code.